# Azure Durable Function with BlobTrigger not working for large files

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a requirement to upload large CSV files and process each record of the CSV by sending it to a 3rd party.

> The 3rd party can take minutes to process the records and there's a
> limitation of number of requests 3rd party can handle concurrently
> therefore I used DurableFunction for this

Here's the flow I'm using

[image]

This was working fine for a while but now I observed this was working for smaller files but when I upload large files they are not getting processed. In the logs I observed below,

```
2023-08-13T14:01:29Z   [Verbose]   Blob 'file_15000-3' will be skipped for function 
'FileUploadBlobTrigger' because this blob with ETag '"0x8DB9C053CC8E3D8"' has already 
been processed. PollId: '64b8b6d2-5d7a-4904-b9bc-8b2258f02ab9'. Source: 'ContainerScan'.
```

Blob trigger

```
public class FileUploadBlobTrigger
{
    private readonly IfileService _fileService;

    public FileUploadBlobTrigger(IfileService fileService)
    {
        _fileService = fileService;
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(FileUploadBlobTrigger))]
    public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("%My:Container%/{name}", Connection = "BlobConnectionString")] Stream myBlob,
        string name, ILogger log,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
    {
        // Business logic to get dataModel
        await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(BatchProcess), dataModel);
    }   
}
```

Calls

```
public class BatchProcess
{
    private readonly BlobTriggerConfiguration _blobTriggerConfiguration;
    private readonly IFileService _fileService;
    private readonly ILogger<BatchProcess> _logger;


    public BatchProcess(IOptions<BlobTriggerConfiguration> blobTriggerConfiguration, IFileService fileService, ILogger<BatchProcess> logger)
    {
        _blobTriggerConfiguration = blobTriggerConfiguration.Value;
        _fileService = fileService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [FunctionName(nameof(BatchProcess))]
    public async Task Run(
        [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
    {
        foreach (var batch in batchList)
        {
            var batchModel = new MatchBatchModel
                { batches = batch, Name = input.Name };

            var batchResponse =
                await context.CallActivityAsync<BatchResponses>("Batch", batchModel);
                
            // Combine with another model
        }
    }
}

[FunctionName("Batch")]
public async Task<BatchResponses> Batch(
    [ActivityTrigger] BatchModel context)
{
    // Process file with the 3rd party
    return batchResponse;
}
```

For this I used following setting in `host.json`

```
  "extensions": {
     "durableTask": {
         "maxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 1,
         "maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions": 1
     },
     "blobs": {
      "maxDegreeOfParallelism": 1
     }
  }
```

Comment: The log message, comes from the polling since you set the verbose flag, its normal, The Current durableClient runtime is 5 minutes, is it possible a larger file is causing the durableClient to timeout?

Comment: @PHPNoob Yes this happens mainly with larger files. My assumption was when you mark it as Durable it will override the default function timeout. Will setting `functionTimeout` work or is there any other setting that I have to set

Comment: It will be in the bindings, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2C2x-durable-functions&pivots=programming-language-csharp#host-json